# Preserving index in a RDD in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to create an RDD which contains String elements. Alongside of these elements I would like a number indicating the index of the element. However, I do not want this number to change if I remove elements, as I want the number to be the original index (thus preserving it). It is also important that the order is preserved in this RDD.

If I use zipWithIndex and thereafter remove some elements, will the indexes change? Which function/structure can I use to have unchanged indexes? I was thinking of creating a Pair RDD, however my input data does not contain indexes.

Comment: yes zipWithIndex is the best solution for you . That should meet all of your requirements and I don't think once index is created in your pair RDD it will be altered if you remove an item.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to proceed with zipWithIndex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering rather than deleting. My problem was easily solved by `zipWithIndex` which fulfilled all my requirements.